# How can I use MAXDATE in MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql, select, maxdate

I am working with a scheduling database for events.

I am selecting from series of days and INNER JOINING them into the schedules parent "event". In my selection I want to make a condition where the selection has to be older than the CURDATE. Here is what I have tried but am getting an "improper use of grouping error"

```
SELECT MIN(event_schedule.event_day) as mindate, MAX(event_schedule.event_day) as maxdate, event.event_title  
FROM event_schedule 
INNER JOIN event ON event_schedule.event_id = event.id 
WHERE MAX(event_schedule.event_day) < CURDATE()
GROUP BY event.id
```

Comment: So add a `GROUP BY event.event_title`. All columns that are not the result of an aggregate expression (`SUM()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()`, etc.) have to be listed in a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your query to be the following, you should be fine:

```
SELECT MIN(event_schedule.event_day) as mindate, MAX(event_schedule.event_day) as maxdate, event.event_title  
FROM event_schedule 
INNER JOIN event ON event_schedule.event_id = event.id
GROUP BY event.event_title
HAVING maxdate < CURRENT_DATE()
```

I removed your `WHERE` clause in favor of a `HAVING` clause and added a `GROUP BY` clause. The `GROUP BY` is necessary for the query to run correctly, and the reason you are getting the error is because you have an aggregate function in your `WHERE` clause. The `HAVING` is like `WHERE` in that it is a filter (they are very different) but if you want to filter on an aggregated value, such as `MAX`, you need to do that in the `HAVING`.

Comment: I have never used Having! Cool!  Can I combine a where and a having clause... BTW you are right about the grouping, my actual query has a group but I removed thinking it would be simpler for the question.

Comment: You can use a `WHERE` and a `HAVING` in the same statement. So if you only wanted to see certain `event.event_title`'s, you would add the `WHERE event.event_title IN (....)` before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Correct. The order of statements goes: `SELECT`->`FROM`->`WHERE`->`GROUP BY`->`HAVING`->`ORDER BY`